# Reading second argument in batch file if first argument has commas

Tags: batch-file

```
sample.bat a,b,c,d yes
```

I'm trying to output yes by echoing %2, but the result shows b. I think the comma is also counted as an escape character or something. How do I output yes as 2nd parameter?

Comment: As you recognized the comma is also a parameter delimiter, so you get 5 parameters. `yes` is then in `%5`

Comment: But I want it to be dynamic, sometimes the first parameter can have 6 letters or more.. I want only a space to be recognized as the splitter for the parameters.. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter delimiters are: `,` `;` `=` `<space>` `<tab>` `<0xFF>`

The parameter delimiters cannot be modified, and they cannot be escaped.

The only way to include a delimiter within a parameter is to enclose the parameter in quotes.

```
sample.bat "a,b,c,d" yes
```

You can strip the quotes from the parameter by using the `~` modifier

```
echo %~1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `%*` instead and parse it with your own rules.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ("%*") DO (
  echo first=%%A
  echo second=%%B
)
```