# Is this a bug in windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have found a peculiar issue with batch scripting that I cannot seem to explain.  Maybe its just because I do not know enough about the underpinnings of how batch works but here is an example batch file (test.bat):

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%*") DO (
    echo %%j
)
```

if I call it like so:

```
test.bat ab a,b "a,b"
```

I get this as my output:

```
a,b "a b"
```

Why was the second comma stripped out?  If I escape the comma like so:

```
test.bat ab a,b "a^,b"
```

I get the correct output:

```
a,b "a,b"
```

It is almost like ',' is considered a delimiter by the for loop, but when I look at FOR /?, the only default delim is white space.  Comma is not listed as a delim.  If I specifically state that the delim is a space, I still get this behavior.  If I escape the quotes, I still get this behavior.  Anyways, if comma was a delim, the first comma should also be stripped out right?.  Oddly enough if you try to use 'usebackq' with the for loop, you get the exact opposite.  The first comma is stripped out and the second one is preserved:

```
a b "a,b"
```

Why do I have to escape all commas inside quotes for this to work?  Is there some whindows rule I am missing or is it just a bug in windows batch scripting?

Comment: Your code gives an error C:\Temp>test.bat ab a,b "a,b"
a,b "a b"
The system cannot find the file ê♠.

Answer (score 0):

1. Comma is a separator in command line [Reading second argument in batch file if first argument has commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834169/reading-second-argument-in-batch-file-if-first-argument-has-commas)
2. When you call `FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%*")` , when expanding, it becomes

   FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i in ("ab a,b "a,b"")
   Now you see you have double quotes opening and closing 2 times.
   Hope this helps.
3. My advice, if yo need sophisticated command line parameters parsing use

> ```
> :loop
>  rem you code here
>  shift
> goto :loop
> ```

There're some limitations when using for with %*.

Comment: So why do the two inner quotes get printed?  If it really thinks it was two sets of quotes as in `"ab a,b "a` and `b""`, why would only two out of the 4 quotes get echoed?  And it still uses white space as a delimiter.  Note that `ab` is not printed out instead of `ab a,b"a`.

Comment: That's why I mentioned point 3 in the answer. It still has some strange things. If you want to find deeper - you can do some searches. But if you want to make a script to work - you need a workaround.

Comment: yeah, I can do a workaround but I just was wondering if anyone knew why batch behaves in that way.  This issue has nothing to do with %*.  I could just create a variable and use that instead of %*.  So, limitations of for loops with %* do not apply here.  Comma is not a default delimiter for FOR loops.  I have looked online but have found nothing on the subject.

Comment: Comma, equals and some other characters are treated as whitespace on the command line, unless quoted.  Inside the for /f it is like a commend line and has some extra limitations.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "line=a b a,b "a,b""
SET line
ECHO [%*]
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%*") DO (ECHO %%j)
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%line%") DO (ECHO %%j)
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("!line!") DO (ECHO %%j)
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%i IN ('echo %line%') DO (ECHO %%j)

GOTO :EOF
```

Running the above may point to an explanation. It's all a matter of history - quite when a substitution is made - %var% first, %%x second and !var! third.

Comment: I still do not get why the comma is removed.  What is removing it and why?  I dont get what the order of substitution has to do with a comma getting dropped.  Obviously `!line!` is getting substituted differently than `%line%` but why?